# JavaScript touch event clicks underneath layer

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile, touch

I have toggle navigation and feature, when you click outside menu (on the `div` with blurry filter) navigation is closing. I had a problem with it on IOS mobiles, so I added touch events. Now it is ok, but there is an another problem - when I click outside menu to trigger closing function, the body content underneath is clicking as well. How to prevent this?

JS code:

```
var sideNav = document.getElementById('Sidenav');
var sliderFilter = document.getElementById('sliderFilter');

function touchHandler () {
        if (event.target.closest("#Sidenav")) {
            // This is a click inside. Do nothing, just return.
            return;
    }
    // This is a click outside.
    closeNav();
}

function openNav() {
    sideNav.classList.add('open');
    sliderFilter.classList.add('open');
    document.addEventListener('click', touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeNav() {
    sideNav.classList.remove('open');
    sliderFilter.classList.remove('open');
    document.removeEventListener('click', touchHandler, true);
    document.removeEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.removeEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've removed `touchstart` event and left just `touchend` and it works properly now.